# Julia: setting up git

Tags: git, julia

Julia have Git program/distributed version control system (`git.exe`, shell - `sh.exe` etc.) in her package. I have already installed Git (I think it's more than 1 time) so Julia's Git is redundant, I guess.

I have tried to just unpack Julia without git directory but `Pkg.add` function ( for example `Pkg.add("Distributions")` ) hasn't worked correctly. It displayed an error:

```
ERROR: could not start process `sh -c "cd 'C:\Documents and Settings\Darek\.julia\.cache\BinDeps' && git rev-parse --git-dir"
`: no such file or directory (ENOENT)
 in test_success at process.jl:460
 in success at process.jl:468
 in readbytes at process.jl:429
 in readall at process.jl:437
 in dir at git.jl:12
 in git at git.jl:18
 in cmd at git.jl:23
 in run at git.jl:24
 in set_remote_url at git.jl:96
 in prefetch at pkg/cache.jl:18
 in resolve at pkg/entry.jl:341
 in resolve at pkg/entry.jl:316
 in edit at pkg/entry.jl:24
 in add at pkg/entry.jl:44
 in add at pkg/entry.jl:48
 in anonymous at pkg/dir.jl:25
 in cd at file.jl:32
 in cd at pkg/dir.jl:25
 in add at pkg.jl:19
```

I unpacked git directory into Julia directory and `Pkg.add` worked correctly.

I have 2 questions:

1. Does Julia's Git differ from other Git? For example does it has some exe files that *normal git* doesn't have? If yes, what do I have to copy-paste?
2. How to set up Julia to use my other git (directory) so I can delete git folder from the Julia's directory?

ps. I'm on windows xp, if that matters.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add what you did to get the first error you posted? Secondly, why do you want to delete a git folder?

Comment: @Milktrader I edited the question. I want to delete git folder because I do not want to have many copies of the same program.

Comment: On my machine, in Julia's source directory, `find -iname git` returns only one thing, namely a folder inside `deps/llvm-3.4` with the contents `find-rev` (an executable) - i.e. my Julia directory does not contain a git installation. I tested to search for `*git` and `git*` as well, but found nothing indicating an installation of git within Julia. Are you sure that's what you have deleted, and not something like a `.git` folder (which all git repositories necessarily have) or `git.jl` (which is just a Julia wrapper around some git commands)?

Comment: @TomasLycken It is `Git` directory. The latest release ( http://s3.amazonaws.com/julialang/bin/winnt/x86/0.2/julia-0.2.1-win32.exe ) contain that directory too. Git directory doesn't contain any jl files. `git.jl` is in the `Julia\julia-05c6461b55\share\julia\base`

Answer (score 2):

I have found the answer for 2:

- Add path to the `Git\bin` (in my case: C:\RailsInstaller\Git\bin )
- Restart the computer (logout and login should be sufficient)

Answer (score 1):

Let me start an answer and I can add to it.

To set up Julia's git-oriented package system, you need to invoke this while in the Julia REPL

`julia> Pkg.init()`

This will create a `.julia` directory in your home directory. It will also set up a directory inside  called `v0.3` and all the fun happens in `~/.julia/v0.3`. Once you have this process completed, you can start adding packages with the `Pkg.add("TimeSeries")` command (shameless plug for a package name). This will create a separate git repo inside the directory.

Suppose a new method is added to TimeSeries called `timetravel()`. Once the dev takes care of the work on his/her end, you can get the updated package by simply calling `Pkg.update()` from REPL.

The package git directory is separate from the code base for the language. I keep mine in a directory called `~/git/julia` and from time to time I do a `$ git pull` to get any updates. Once the language repo is updated, it requires a `$ make clean && make` to build the new additions.

note: I'm not sure what you mean when you say "Julia have git in her package"

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear what I mean by `Git`.